# Creating multiple users in one txt file Admin or Customer

Tags: python

hi I wanna ask is it possible to create a login system to allow it to recognize the user is an admin or a customer in the same text file, I just don't know how to show that that person is an admin or a customer, whenever I log in if I choose login as an admin I'm available to use the customer's credentials to log in which I don't want to happen sorry I just learned how to use files in python its for my school project any help will be appreciated :( so far this is what I have

```
def homepage():
  print("Welcome to our Store!")
  print("Would you like to Login or Register")
  print("or login as an admin")
  user_type = (input("Select an option: "))

  if user_type.lower() == "login":
      signin()

  elif user_type.lower() == "register":
      register()

  elif user_type.lower() == "admin":
      adminlogin()   
  else:
      restart()
homepage()

def restart():
  print("We are truly sorry that you have experienced a problem, please contact our admins")
  option = input('Would you like to return to the main menu? Y/N ')
  if option == 'Y':
      homepage()
  else:
      print("Thank you came again")

def signin():
  database = open("DatabaseLogin.txt", "r")
  username  = input("Enter a username:")
  password  = input("Enter a password:")

  if username and password in database.read():
      print("Login Successfull")
      print("Welcome Back! :)")
  else:
      print("Incorrect password or username")
      restart()

def register():
  database = open("database.txt", "r")
  username  = input("Enter a username:")
  password  = input("Enter a password:")
  password1 = input("Confirm password:")

  if password != password1:
      print("Password does not match")
      register()
  else:
      database = open("database.txt", "a")
      database.write(username+", " +password+"\n")
      print("You have been registered! :)")

def adminlogin():
  database = open("DatabaseLogin.txt", "r")
  username  = input("Enter a username:")
  password  = input("Enter a password:")

  if username and password in database.read():
      print("Login Successfull")
      print("Welcome Back Admin! :)")
  else:
      print("Incorrect password or username")
      restart()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to store all admin usernames in a separate file and check in `adminlogin` whether username is in this file.

I'd like to give some more advices on issues in your code:

- `if username and password in database.read()` means "If username exists and password in database", you should consider using `if username in database.read() and password in database.read()`
- It would be better if you delimit entries of one record (username and password) with one line break and delimit between records with some other character string (double line break, for example)
- With your current code there are many cases when user can get access with incorrect credentials. For example: try to input in both username and password fields some existing username. This will work even if you fix the issue #1. To correct this issue you should first find the record with corresponding username and then check the password (see previous advice)

There are many things to be improved. Please ask if you want improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store admin and customer information in the same file you can add additional section to the file other than user and password sections which represents whether the login information is for customer or admin.

For example:

`”C,username,password”` for customer.

`”A,username,password”` for admin.

Then you can write a function to read the file line by line and check username, password and section tells whether the information is about a customer or an admin.

Additionally if you want to simulate a login information database read file chunk by chunk for best practice, because due to memory constraints you can’t handle large files with this way.

Comment: My text file is like this but I don't know how to write the code to read the file line by line and check the username, password, and section to tell whether the information is about a customer or an admin.

Text file:
Gavin gavin123 Admin
Jaimensingh teddy123 Customer